# How to use linear programming to get an optimal mixed strategy in 2 player normal form games

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

I am reading [Computing the Optimal Strategy to Commit to](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esandholm/Computing%20commitment%20strategy.ec06.pdf) by Conitzer and Sandholm recently.

And I have trouble in understanding how to use linear programming to find an optimal
mixed strategy for 2-player normal-form games. The authors said in Theorem 2. "In 2-player normal-form games, an optimal mixed strategy to commit to can be found in polynomial time
using linear programming."

I have no trouble in understand the statement and the proof of Theorem 2. But actually confused by how to solve the linear program below.

[image]

Specifically, how to transform the constraints condition $\sum_{s\in S} p_s u_f(s,t) \ge\sum_{s\in S} p_s u_f(s,t') $ to a detail inequality. Like $a_1x_1 + \cdots a_nx_n \le b$ in  canonical form (Standard form) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) of linear programming. Then maybe I can solve it by simplex algorithm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "x" are the $p_s$. Therefore you can write the equality constraint as $\sum_{s\in S} x_s = 1$. The values of $u_f(s,t)$ are just the outcome when player 1 uses the pure strategy s and player 2 uses pure strategy t. These are just real numbers that can be plugged in. The inequality constraints are just $a_{1,t}x_1 + a_{2,t}x_2 + .. + a_{|S|,t}x_{|S|} \geq a_{1,t'}x_1 + a_{2,t'}x_2 + .. + a_{|S|,t'}x_{|S|}$ where $a_{s,t} = u_f(s,t)$ or $(a_{1,t'} - a_{1,t})x_1 + ... + (a_{|S|,t'} - a_{|S|,t})x_{|S|} \leq 0$.

Comment: For specific $t'$, we can know the value of $a_{s,t'}$ for $s \in S$. But $t$ is unknown so is $a_{s,t}$  (i.e. $u_f(s,t)$). Then $\sum_{s \in S} (a_{s,t'} - a_{s,t})x_s \le 0$ remain  undecided coefficients for $x_s$.

Comment: This isn't true, you know all the $a_{s,t}$. Let's consider an example. If we are playing rock paper scissors, let $s=1$ be rock, $s=2$ be paper and $s=3$ be scissors. The value of $a_{s,t} = u_{f}(s,t)$ is the outcome of the game when player 1 uses pure strategy $s$ and player 2 uses pure strategy $t$. So $a_{1,3}$ would be the outcome of player 1 using rock and player 2 using scissors. If we make a win worth 1, a draw worth 0, and a loss be -1 then we can assign the value $a_{1,3} = 1$. Without knowing anything about what strategies players used we can assign the value of $a_{s,t}$.

Comment: The optimization problem is trying to find the optimal strategy, i.e., what *probability* to assign to each pure strategy. Another way to look at it is that the sum represents the expected value when using strategy $x$ given $t$ vs the expected value of using strategy $x$ given $t'$. The inequality is imposing the constraint that the optimal strategy gives the highest expected value for any pure strategy player 2 uses.

Comment: @dgadjov, I still have some questions. I am not quite clear with the rock paper scissors game analogy, since the game is happened simultaneously. But the game here is a leader-follower game.  For simplicity, Let' assume leader and follower have 2 strategies ,respectively. So, leader has $s_1, s_2$, follower has $t_1,t_2$. Hence $u_f(s,t)$ has 4 values, $u_f(s_1,t_1), u_f(s_1,t_2), u_f(s_2,t_1), u_f(s_2,t_2)$. These values are known to us. Now the constraint is $\sum_{s\in S} p_s u_f(s,t) \ge\sum_{s\in S} p_s u_f(s,t') $.

Comment: i.e. $p_{s_1}u_f(s_1,t) + p_{s_2}u_f(s_2,t) \ge p_{s_1}u_f(s_1,t_1) + p_{s_2}u_f(s_2,t_1)$ and $p_{s_1}u_f(s_1,t) + p_{s_2}u_f(s_2,t) \ge p_{s_1}u_f(s_1,t_2) + p_{s_2}u_f(s_2,t_2)$. I should first determine $t$ then seek how to maxmize $p_{s_1}u_l(s_1,t) + p_{s_2}u_l(s_2,t)$ ?

Comment: In the paper they say "For every pure follower strategy t, we compute a
mixed strategy for the leader..." So you need to do it for each t. The paper also states "program may be infeasible for some follower strategies t ... Nevertheless, the program must be feasible for at least some follower strategies; among these follower strategies, choose a strategy $t^*$ that maximizes the linear program’s solution value...  If the leader chooses as her mixed strategy the optimal settings of the variables $p$ for $t^*$ and the follower plays t∗, this constitutes an optimal strategy profile."

Comment: I found a nice example to explain the LP method used here. It's in page 7 of [this](https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/CS580/fa2022/Slides/Lec18-StackelbergNashbargaining.pdf). Hope this will help someone who has same trouble in understanding.